# I want to use the same google script twice on a google sheet but it will only run once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote this script for google sheets and want to use it twice in the same sheet.  When I put them in the same script part of the sheet it only runs one of them and not both of them.

Here is the of I've been putting the script in:

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "INPUT1";//these are global Cooper Edit
var sourceWorksheetName = "INPUT1";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "INPUT1";
var targetWorksheetName = "INPUT1";

function importData1() {
  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
  toWorksheet.clearContents();
  toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.length, thisData[0].length).setValues(thisData); 
}



    var sourceSpreadsheetID = "INPUT2";//these are global Cooper Edit
    var sourceWorksheetName = "INPUT2";
    var targetSpreadsheetID = "INPUT2";
    var targetWorksheetName = "INPUT2";

    function importData2() {
      var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
      var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
      var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
      var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
      toWorksheet.clearContents();
      toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.length, thisData[0].length).setValues(thisData); 
    }
```

Cooper Edit: The global declarations get run everytime you run every function.

Comment: See my edits.  The solution is to put all of the global declaration within the function declarations and your problem will go away.

Comment: ahh ok!  so just adding { //these are global } will help?  Just want to make sure I understand!!! Thank you Cooper

Comment: I'm not sure you understand.  The lines that I marked in your question that are outside of the function declaration are global and they get evaluate every time that you call a function and the  way that you have means that every time you call one of the functions that uses them they will always be using INPUT2 because that's the last one in the file.  So I recommend that you put them inside of the function declaration.

Comment: Ahh ok yes I understand now

Comment: This is one thing that is different from the clientside situation where the global parameters can be changed by the functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run both the function from a single call then add a middleman which will call both the functions. for eg

```
function middleman(){
  importData1();
  importData2();
}
```

Comment: Wait where would I put that to combine the 2?